# sharing an ubuntu applications

Tags: application-development, development

I developed a c++ application depending on a few libraries (qt/boost/R). I would like to share it with a collegue in the easiest way. Our first attempt was simply to copy-paste the compiled binaries from one computer to the other (both of us are on Ubuntu). Doing so, my collegues simply obtained a "binary file impossible to launch". When trying on my colleague computer

```
 ldd myApp
```

I get:

```
  myApp is not an dynamic executable.
```

Any help/hint/link to solve our problem would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: might be your operating systems architecture and library dependencies differs. that could be a reason of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Package it

you have to package your application to share with your friends, use debian packaging is the recommended packaging for ubuntu unless it is a phone app.

Alternatively you can create windows like installers using bitrock